# Can Freemarker macro parameters use other parameters for their default values?

Tags: freemarker

We have a number of Freemarker macros to simplify HTML pages, eg `<@macro.textfield id name label .../>` can automatically add a label tag, standard CSS classes, etc. To cover all our use cases, there are a number of parameters with default values.

However, we would ideally like more advanced defaults than simple literals. For example, if a text field doesn't have a custom `value` specified, then it should default to getting it from the model using the `name` parameter, eg `${parameters[name]!}`. The name, in turn, can usually be derived from the ID; a field with `id="foo"` will most likely need `name="form.foo"`. Is there an efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default value is just a usual expression, thus it can refer to a data model variable (among others) like this: `<#macro something name=form.name>`. It can also refer to another macro parameter: `<#macro something p1 p2=p1>`. (Order doesn't mater, FreeMarker will figure out the correct evaluation order. Even cyclic dependencies like `p1=p2 p2=p1` are allowed, as it can be resolved when you specify at least one of the parameters in the call.)

See also: https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/ref_directive_macro.html#ref.directive.macro

Comment: Huh, I thought I'd tried that without success, but I must have been doing something else wrong at the time, because yes, that works. Just need to work around the order of precedence bug when ending the expression with a bang. Thanks :)

Comment: @ThrawnCA Perhaps that's not really because of the precedence bug. `<macro foo x=y! z>` is ambiguous, as the right hand operand of `!` is optional. Of course you can put things into `()` to get what you mean.